# How to fix update problem in Talend Studio?

Tags: talend

there are updates. But I get always:

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Us1v.png)

But if I retry to update all libraries in dialog
additional talend package the number of libraries
which has to be updated is decreased. So a workaround
is to click on update again and again until
all libraries are updated. How can i fix that?

[in row Required third-party libraries is decreased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knxrK.png)

thanks

Comment: I think there is a 'download all' option in this popup or something similar. Can you check ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, option download and install all is activated. But problem still existing.